# Where do I place the return of a function in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist, return

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function in JAVA that searches through a document line per line:
First I initialize the file and a reader, then convert each line to a string in an ArrayList; after that I try to check the ArrayList against a String to then return the position of the ArrayList as a string.

So for example I have a text containing:
1 - Somewhere over the rainbow
2 - Way up high.

Converted to ArrayList, if then searched for: "Somewhere"; then it should return the sentence "Somewhere over the rainbow";

Here is the code I tried; but it keeps returning 'null';

```
String FReadUtilString(String line) {
    File file = new File(filepath);
    ArrayList<String> lineReader = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println();


    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String outputReader;

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            lineReader.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();

        for(int count = 0; count < lineReader.size(); count++) {
            if(lineReader.get(count).contains(line)){outputReader = lineReader.get(count);}
        }
    } catch (Exception linereadeline) {
        System.out.println(linereadeline);
    }
    return outputReader;
}
```

Comment: `outputReader` isn't doing anything because your program is made to find the first match. In this case you should simply `return lineReader.get(count);` instead of keeping it in the `outputReader`.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Checking if your Array contains the expected Strings?

Comment: Can you clearify a bit? Do I simply edit the return to be 'LineReader.get(count); or what do I do?

Comment: Btw. please use some reasonable variable names. `lineReader` is not a Reader, it is an array containing lines. `outputReader` isn't a Reader either, it's some "result".

Comment: @Amongalen: I'll think about being a bit more specific in the future. I guess it would make the code more readable.

Comment: You can return right when you were trying to keep it in `outputReader`. Anyway, I don't think this compiles because `outputReader` is in the scope of `try-catch` but your return statement is after the `try-catch`.

Comment: @Jai **or** OP has a shadowed class variable named `outputReader` which is `null` because the local variable which was actually assigned a value goes out of scope. Variable names could be a lot more meaningful. Why name an `Exception` `linereadeline` for example? Why re-read the file on every method invocation? Etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that sure sounds like the perfect recipe to make debugging takes forever.

Comment: @Jai: I did as you told in this case; but how come the String 'outputReader' doesn't return after the try-catch? But if I don't place a return statement after the block I get a compile error?

Comment: @JurgenRutten Most likely you are doing what Elliott was saying. Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch good question. I found that I need to make each block of code shorter in a lot of cases since most of my errors come from repeating blocks.I'm taking lessons but still full on noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactor your code a bit, but I keep your logic, it should work for you:

```
String FReadUtilString(String line, String fileName){
    File file = new File(fileName);
    List<String> lineReader = new ArrayList<>();
    String outputReader =  "";
  
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file))
    {
      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        lineReader.add(sc.nextLine());
      }
  
      for (int count = 0; count < lineReader.size(); count++){
        if (lineReader.get(count).contains(line)){
          outputReader = lineReader.get(count);
        }
      }
    }
  
    catch (Exception linereadeline) {
      System.out.println(linereadeline);
    }

    return outputReader;
  }
```

NOTE: I used the try-with-resource statement to ensure the closing of the Scanner.

Comment: `List<String> lineReader = java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());`

Comment: Please add some explanation what was wrong with the initial code. OP is just learning so it's really valuable to know why it wasn't working. (Check Elliott Frisch's comment to the question itself)

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct version:

```
String fReadUtilString(String line, String fileName) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        return lines.filter(l -> l.contains(line)).findFirst();
    }
    catch (Exception linereadeline) {
        System.out.println(linereadeline);  // or just let the exception propagate
    }
}
```